# In Bootstrap 3's table-responsive when below breakpoint dropdown menus can't be used, any assistance for my workaround is most appreciated

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

Output: http://jsbin.com/APuCOwa/3

Edit: http://jsbin.com/APuCOwa/3/edit

When you have a responsive table in Bootstrap 3, when you are below the 767px break point, the dropdown-menus are not accessible because they add content and the content at that size has an overflow:auto or something, so depending on the location of the menu -- if the table itself doesn't have enough height -- the menu shows up and people won't see it. Plus scrollbars are not visible until you scroll on touch.

As a work around, which I need help with, I fudged together another toggle that doesn't close when clicked off and adds a class to the parent (to add height) when the menu is toggled (you must size the output http://jsbin.com/APuCOwa/3 down below 767px) to see this. The problem is that when the user clicks another toggle while one is open the class added to the parent is removed, tried toggleClass and this thing (which is the same) and it's the same result.

Essentially, when you click a toggle, it opens, adds height to the parent "table-responsive" div wrapper, and when you toggle off it undoes that, so far that's good, but if you click another menu while one is open, that is where I can't figure it out. Since they are all isolated menus, this is confusing to me.

I am not so hot with jQuery.

Output: http://jsbin.com/APuCOwa/3

Edit: http://jsbin.com/APuCOwa/3/edit

BTW: Firefox, at least mine, has issues with jsbin, Chrome does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close all on click and only (re)open it when it wasn't open only:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.table-responsive .dropdown-toggle').click(function(event){

  var open = $(this).hasClass('open');

$('.table-responsive .dropdown-menu').hide('fast');
$(".table-responsive").removeClass("res-drop");
$('.table-responsive .dropdown-toggle').removeClass('open');  
if(!open)
{  
$(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('fast');
$(this).parents(".table-responsive").addClass("res-drop");
$(this).addClass('open');
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had dynamic heights so Bass Jobsen solution didn't work properly.

I decided to rely on data attributes to store the current height of parent div e then restore on dropdown close.

Here is my code:

```
 var isOpen = !($(this).parent().hasClass("open"));

    var menuHeight = $(this).siblings(".dropdown-menu").height();
    var increaseHeightBy = menuHeight * 1.3;

    var originalHeight = $(this).closest(".table-responsive").attr('data-original-height');

    if (isOpen && !originalHeight) {
        originalHeight = $(this).closest(".table-responsive").height();
        $(this).closest(".table-responsive").attr('data-original-height', originalHeight);
        $(this).closest(".table-responsive").height(originalHeight + increaseHeightBy);
    }

    if (!isOpen && originalHeight) {
        $(this).closest(".table-responsive").height(originalHeight);
        $(this).closest(".table-responsive").removeAttr('data-original-height');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the dropdown menu to fixed position and close it when the window's resized. Not a perfect solution but it works.

```
// Responsive tables with dropdown buttons
$('.table-responsive .dropdown-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var button = $(this),
        menu = button.next('.dropdown-menu');

    menu.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: button.offset().top + button.outerHeight() - $(window).scrollTop(),
        right: $(window).width() - (button.offset().left + button.outerWidth())
    });

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        menu.css({
            top: button.offset().top + button.outerHeight() - $(window).scrollTop()
        });
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $('.dropdown-backdrop').trigger('click');
        button.blur();
        $(window).off('resize scroll');
    });
});
```