# How to keep Bootstrap dropdown always on top

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are using Bootstrap 3 Dropdown however, it looks like this when there is a horizontal scroll bar that the container `div` shows when the page is not big enough in width. Please aware that it is not the scroll bar of the browser window. The scrollbar clips the dropdown like below:

[image]

I have checked `dropdown-menu` which is associated with the `ul` element that is the dropdown and it looks fine to me:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Later I checked whether the container `div` has any `z-index` defined but I couldn't find any. But it has a class called `table-responsive` and it looks like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px)
.table-responsive {
margin-bottom: 15px;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change overflow-y from hidden to visible?

Comment: @khilley: Didn't change anything unfortunately. I have actually tried several of them but no luck.

Comment: jsbin link maybe?  That would make it easier to debug

Comment: This is a problem with the table-responsive. They don't support dropdowns inside table-responsive. See last comment in this thread: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11037

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11037 -- also see the very, very last comment, after the issue was closed, this provides some jquery to fix it in some situations

Comment: I don't think you can. `.table-responsive` needs that `overflow-y` in order to work, but will obviously hide your dropdown, so unless you find some solution involving jQuery or JS, I don't think it's possible

Comment: @Fabio is correct. This has been addressed and will not be fixed. There is no fix. That is, they won't write js to fix it.

Comment: also, you're a seasoned user, you know you need MUCH MORE code than that to solve your issue. Anyways, here's a Bootply for anyone that wants to take a stab http://www.bootply.com/77Aldw2Mzl

Comment: Already did, in that thread, you toggle the class and add some height to the parent, other than that, clone and position outside. There's a script to be written.

Comment: @Fabio: I thought that could be a known problem within Bootstrap, so this amount of code could give some lead for people but thanks for sharing that link!

Comment: @Tarik I know you didn't do it in bad faith, hence the "seasoned user" comment and why I added the code, what I meant is that HTML is the main part of the equation, because by seeing your image, there's something that jumps to the view at first glimpse: you really don't need a wide table (hence overflowing), thus it looks to me you're adding a layer of complication that you could easily solve by just using the width you need and nothing else. Or even better: why a table for something that isn't tabular data?

Comment: I had some help with this last year: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606828/in-bootstrap-3s-table-responsive-when-below-breakpoint-dropdown-menus-cant-be -- the question has the fix in it first link and the second answer is also useful

Comment: If you add position: absolute to the .btn-group div, this seems to work in the Bootply from @Fabio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer. First of all, change `btn-group`'s `position` css rule from `relative` to `inherit`.

```
$("#dropdownMenu").on("show.bs.dropdown", function () {
    // For difference between offset and position: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3202038/44852
    var dropdownButtonPosition = $(this).position();
    var dropdownButtonOffset = $(this).offset();
    var dropdownButtonHeight = $(this).height();
    var dropdownMenu = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu:first");
    var dropdownMenuHeight = dropdownMenu.height();
    var scrollToTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    // It seems there are some numbers that don't get included so I am using some tolerance for
    // more accurate result.
    var heightTolerance = 17;

    // I figured that window.innerHeight works more accurate on Chrome
    // but it is not available on Internet Explorer. So I am using $(window).height() 
    // method where window.innerHeight is not available.
    var visibleWindowHeight = window.innerHeight || $(window).height();

    var totalHeightDropdownOccupies = dropdownMenuHeight +
        dropdownButtonOffset.top + dropdownButtonHeight + heightTolerance - scrollToTop;

    // If there is enough height for dropdown to fully appear, then show it under the dropdown button,
    // otherwise show it above dropdown button.
    var dropdownMenuTopLocation = totalHeightDropdownOccupies < visibleWindowHeight
        ? dropdownButtonPosition.top + dropdownButtonHeight
        : dropdownButtonPosition.top - dropdownMenuHeight - dropdownButtonHeight + heightTolerance;

    dropdownMenu.css("left", dropdownButtonPosition.left)
        .css("top", dropdownMenuTopLocation);
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem when i use <div class="*table-responsive*"> <table>